# How to import my data from Android into my new iPhone?

Tags: ios, backup, data-transfer, iphone

I recently changed my phone (it was an Android smartphone) to a new iPhone 7. I want to export and import a lot of files from my Android device to my iPhone but I do not know how to proceed. I have already tried it manually but it is a long and tiring job. What is a faster method?

Comment: Have you tried using Apple's "Move to iOS" app for your Android phone (available on the Google Play store)

Comment: No, I have never used it. Is it  a faster method ? 
Can you explain me how it works ? Thank you.

Comment: See [this post](http://www.imore.com/how-move-your-photos-contacts-and-more-android-iphone) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apple's official [**Move to iOS**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios) app, available on Google Play. This automatically moves the content you select from your Android phone to your iPhone. Install the app on your Android device and follow the instructions.

[Move from Android to iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201196)